# Mysql error: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-functions, mysql-error-1415

I am trying to have a conditional change in a parameter for update statement.
I am getting the following error when I try the following function

```
/home/y/bin/mysql -u root < testpri.sql > out
ERROR 1415 (0A000) at line 4: Not allowed to return a result set from a function
```

Contents of testpri.sql are as follows:

```
use `zestdb`;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS UPDATEPASSWD;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION UPDATEPASSWD(n INT) RETURNS varchar(255) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
    DECLARE mypasswd varchar(255);
    IF (n = 1) THEN
       SET mypasswd = '12ccc1e5c3c9203af7752f937fca4ea6263f07a5';
       SELECT 'n is 1' AS ' ';
    ELSE
       SET mypasswd = '1a7bc371cc108075cf8115918547c3019bf97e5d';
       SELECT 'n is 0' AS ' ';
    END IF;>
    SELECT CONCAT('mypasswd is ', mypasswd) AS ' ';
    RETURN mypasswd;
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL UPDATEPASSWD(0);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's actually your debugging `SELECT` calls.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html):

> Statements that return a result set can be used within a stored procedure but not within a stored function. This prohibition includes SELECT statements that do not have an INTO var_list clause...

Answer (score 0):

I arrived in search of answers to the same question, and found another way to work around the issue, so that I can use the SELECT statement that is the heart and soul of the MySQL function that elicited the warning.

Consider the following snippet.

SET intNMatches = ( SELECT COUNT(*) ...

SET coerces the SELECT statement to return its one and only column, a row count, into intNMatches, a local variable cast to BIGINT. Since it contains trade secrets, I can't show the rest of the query. Suffice it to say that the query installs without causing the MySQL engine to issue a warning.